# ¿Como seleccionar un grupo devuelto de un group by?

Tags: oracle

En resumidas cuentas necesito seleccionar en base a un cliente las empresas que se encargan de pagar por el servicio que el presta, pensé agrupar por empresa con un group by, pero seleccionar por empresa y que muestre todos los pagos que realizo a el cliente, eso en una consulta inicial, en una segunda consulta otra empresa con los mismos campos y así sucesivamente.

poseo una tabla de pagos, donde un cliente puede tener varias empresas que le paguen y estas realizar varios pagos a un cliente(no en la mayoría de casos), donde en el group by agrupo por empresa, ya que es la información que necesito mostrar, el tema esta en seleccionar una de las empresas que me trae el group by, pero no se como hacerlo.

Ej: SELECT EMPRESA, PAGO_CLIENTE, CLIENTE, FECHA FROM PAGOS GROUP BY EMPRESA;

El tema es que en ningún caso por los datos ser dinámicos podría hacer una condición where, toda la informacion de cada cliente es diferente.

Aqui esta como se me muestran los datos
[image: muestra1]

Aqui como los necesito

[image: muestra2]

Comment: Considera por favor mejorar tu pregunta basándonos en [ask], no termina de quedar clara

Comment: Porfa explica un poco mejor... ¿Quieres seleccionar una empresa en base a qué? ¿Necesitas datos adicionales que están también en la tabla? ¿Quieres un registro por empresa o un registro por cliente?

Comment: Podrias mostrar un ejemplo de lo que tenes y lo que queres obtener? asi como esta, es dificil entender que queres...

Comment: Y otra cosa.. en que base de datos estas trabajando? pusiste 3 diferentes...

Comment: Y cual es la logica de mostrar 3 registros iguales?

Comment: Para ese caso en particular se muestran los 3 registros iguales, hay caso en los que no, de todos modos es por tema de tener un promedio del dinero que se le ha estado pagando y mostrar que cantidades, no importa que sean iguales

Comment: No entiendo bien de donde sale el 3er  registro en tu ejemplo... ¿Hay más info aparte de la que muestras en la primera imagen? ¿O es simplemente una repetición? No veo ninguna diferencia aparte de cambiar el orden o algo que podría hacerse con un `WHERE EMPRESA='Empresa1'` .... tampoco veo el "promedio" al que te refieres en ninguna parte